# Electric flux through a sphere

Tags: electrostatics

I have read that flux through a sphere having charge q inside it is q/ε⁰ i.e it is independent of the radius . But we  know that also Φ = E.S and E is non uniform because the field lines become more spaced as we go further . So shouldn't flux decrease with radius ?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the surface area $S$ of the enclosing sphere also increases as we go further from the point charge.  In particular, this implies that the electric field strength $E$ should be inversely proportional to $S$;  and since $S$ is itself proportional to $r^2$, this implies that $E \propto 1/r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

electric flux describes about the total no of electric field lines crossing a surface and no of field lines depends only on the magnitude of the charge inside that area and the medium in which it is present and is independent of the dimensions of the surface. 
we can say this even mathematically, we know that Φ = E.S 
$$E=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}\;(assuming\; medium\;is\;air)  $$
$$S=4\pi R^2$$
$$E.S=\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\therefore Φ=\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$